# python / asyncio: re-schedule a coroutine scheduled by call_later (e.g. heartbeat)

Tags: python, python-asyncio

best way to call a coroutine e.g. 5sec after the last time something happened?

Example:
Assume I have a resource that I only want to keep open while it's needed, but that takes some time to initialize (e.g. a webcam).

Example code:

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, Depends
import asyncio

def create_app():
    app = FastAPI()
    app._my_resource = None
    app._my_resource_close= None

    def _close_my_resource():
        print("closing resource")
        app._my_resource = None
        app._my_resource_close = None

    async def my_resource():
        if app._my_resource is None:
            print("opening resource")
            app._my_resource = "Hello World"
            app._my_resource_close = asyncio.get_running_loop().call_later(5, _close_my_resource)
        else:
            #TODO: is there a way to "reschedule" app._my_resource_close instead of this?
            app._my_resource_close.cancel()
            app._my_resource_close = asyncio.get_running_loop().call_later(5, _close_my_resource)

        return app._my_resource
        
    @app.get("/")
    def index(res = Depends(my_resource)):
        return {"my_resource": res}

    return app
```

this works, but is canceling the task and re-creating it really necessary? Is there no way to "bump" the execution another e.g. 5 seconds

Comment: Maintain a `last_used_time` attribute for that resource. Modify `_close_my_resource` to check that attribute and only close the resource if `last_used_time > threshold_time`. Arrange to call `_close_my_resource` periodically (or just make it a looping task).

Comment: Its bad, but you can just access the underlying `_when` variable on `app._my_resource_close` and it will modify/delay the execution. You should probably make a custom class for handling delaying the execution of the coroutine, I am not sure how to do that though

Comment: do not accesstheunderlying `_when`  - actually cancelling and recreating a new task, with the new time is the official wayt o do it.  "_when" starts with an underscore indicating it is not guaranteed future implementations will use it, or honor it in the same way.

Comment: hmm, don't really like the idea of having a permanent background job (one more thing that you have to clean up at shutdown) and modifying `_when` is really not a good option.

found an example doing something similar, basically re-creating the task seems to be the way to go:
https://github.com/sopel-irc/sopel/blob/17bb5b9f1ba2f8d45be537977fd80e6349a251e7/sopel/irc/backends.py#L148